# how can i make sign up form using antd library in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, alignment, antd, google-web-designer

[I am new in using this library / I just want to know how can I make follow form with proper alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SURo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code example will help you

```
import { Button, Checkbox, Form, Input } from 'antd';
import React from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log('Success:', values);
  };

  const onFinishFailed = (errorInfo) => {
    console.log('Failed:', errorInfo);
  };

  return (
    <Form
      name="basic"
      labelCol={{
        span: 8,
      }}
      wrapperCol={{
        span: 16,
      }}
      initialValues={{
        remember: true,
      }}
      onFinish={onFinish}
      onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
      autoComplete="off"
    >
      <Form.Item
        label="Username"
        name="username"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: 'Please input your username!',
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        label="Password"
        name="password"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: 'Please input your password!',
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input.Password />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        name="remember"
        valuePropName="checked"
        wrapperCol={{
          offset: 8,
          span: 16,
        }}
      >
        <Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        wrapperCol={{
          offset: 8,
          span: 16,
        }}
      >
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Grid Components](https://ant.design/components/grid/) to structure your from as you wish. 
A simple way to do so is:

```html
 <Form>
 <Row>
 <Col span={12}>
 <Form.Item label="First Name">
 <Input />
 </Form.Item>
 </Col>
 <Col span={12}>
 <Form.Item label="Last Name">
 <Input />
 </Form.Item>
 </Col>
 <Col span={12}>
 <Form.Item label="Phone Number">
 <Input />
 </Form.Item>
 </Col>
 <Col span={12}>
 <Form.Item label="Email Address">
 <Input />
 </Form.Item>
 </Col>
 <Col span={24}>
 <Form.Item label="Address">
 <Input />
 </Form.Item>
 </Col>
 <Col span={12}>
 <Form.Item label="City">                                                        
  <Input />                        
  </Form.Item>
  </Col>
   .
   .
   .
   
          
 </Row> 
 </Form>
```

Make sure too read documents: 
https://ant.design/components/grid/ 
https://ant.design/components/form/